# iOS Check if an iTunes account is logged in

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to check if an iTunes account is logged into a device?

I have an in-app purchase setup and if the user makes a purchase I write to NSUserDefaults; however, if the iTunes account used to make the purchase is logged out (or another is signed in), NSUserDefaults isn't reset.

So, is there a way I can reset NSUserDefaults when an iTunes account is logged out.  Or, perhaps there's a better way for me to determine whether or not the user has made an in-app purchase.

Thank you.

Comment: same thing i want to know.do you have any way ?

Comment: No, I ended up removing the in-app purchase in question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

No. Instead, I would recommend using the built-in mechanisms to accomplish this.

You can see if the user has minimized the app and come back by subscribing to the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification (or using your `UIApplicationDelegate`).

Then, you should be able to simply restore the user's purchases using the `StoreKit` framework and compare against what you have stored for the current user to see if they have changed accounts.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html

Comment: There are a couple possible problems with that: 1. The user isn't connected to the internet and 2. Implementing [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] causes the framework to ask the user to sign into iTunes, which is not something you want each time the app is opened.  This does, however, allow me to see how many items the user has purchased (which is exactly what I need).